# Set multiple values

Tags: json, jq

Given this file

```
{
  "[global]": {
    "current": "",
    "hash": ""
  }
}
```

I would like this output:

```
{
  "[global]": {
    "current": "alpha",
    "hash": "bravo"
  }
}
```

I have this working command:

```
jq '."[global]".current="alpha" | ."[global]".hash="bravo"' example.json
```

However I would rather not have to repeat the `."[global]"` part. I tried this
command but it only returns part of the input:

```
$ jq '."[global]" | .current="alpha" | .hash="bravo"' example.json
{
  "current": "alpha",
  "hash": "bravo"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [multiplication](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Multiplicationdivisionmoduloand) of objects recursively merges the two.  You can merge the `[global]` object with an object with the new values.  The string values on the RHS will be used in the result.

```
."[global]" *= { current: "alpha", hash: "bravo" }
```

Addtion would work here too, but multiplication is generally more useful, particularly with nested objects.  Rather than replacing corresponding objects, they are also merged.

Comment: Huh, this is perfect. However looking at it now it is actually easier to just build the modified object from scratch

Answer (score 0):

As [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) indicated, the non-recursive `+=` operator will also work in this situation.  Specifically:

```
  ."[global]" += {current: "alpha", hash:"bravo"}
```